# For KNN: How to justify that the probability of points to fall into a sphere of volume $V$ is $p(X)V$

Tags: probability, distributions, k-nearest-neighbour, geometry

[https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lwehbe/10701_S19/files/Lecture_3.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Elwehbe/10701_S19/files/Lecture_3.pdf)

At the end of these notes, there is a short paragraph.

> Let $x$ be a test point. Let $x_1, \ldots, x_K$ be its $K$ nearest
> neighbors. Let $v_x$ be a sphere around $x$ containing its $K$ nearest
> neighbors.
>
> Assuming $x$ is an instance of a random variable $X$ which is
> uniformly distributed in $v_x$. The probability of "points" falling in
> $v_x$ is $p(X) V$, $V$ is the volume of $v_x$.

How does one make sense of this paragraph?

What does it mean for points to fall into $v_x$ (since $X$ is uniform in $v_x$, therefore isn't it guaranteed to generate a point which fall into $v_x$?)

Why is the probability given by $P(X) V$?